# Struct to file in C

Tags: c, file, struct

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct{
  char name[MAXSTRING]; //MAXSTRING is defined above
  int id;
}student;
```

And this `student st` in which  I save a name and an id.

I also have a  file loaded in this: `student *stArray = load(argv[1]); //load()` is a function in which I open the file.

Now I want to add the contents of the `st` to the `stArray` in this function:

```
int addStudent(student st, student *stArray); //It's supposed to insert an entry
```

but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

```
student *load(char *filename){

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "ab+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
        abort();
    }
    
    student *students;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(fp);
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    int numStudents = fileSize/sizeof(student);
    students = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student)*numStudents);
    if (students == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }
    
    return students;
}
```

Comment: What does `load`do exactly ? Source code would be best. The naming suggests that it loads the file and returns an array of student records, which it obviously does not as in this case the job would be done.

Comment: It's not clear what you want `addStudent` to do. Replace an entry in the array in the program's memory? Insert or append an entry, making the array longer? Make some change to the file or create a new file?

Comment: You need to open the file in read mode and then read.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add the contents of the st to the stArray

To add a new student in the already created array just increase its size using *realloc* then copy the new student at its end.

But this is impossible having that signature

> ```
> int addStudent(student st, student *stArray);
> ```

because :

1. you do not know the size of the current array
2. you have no way to return the new array

You need to receive in argument the size of the array or the number of student it memorizes

To return the new array you can return its address :

```
student * addStudent(student st, student *stArray, size_t size);
```

or use a double pointer :

```
int addStudent(student st, student ** stArray, size_t size);
```

but it  seems reasonable to also return the new size else the caller has to update it, so the second solution is probably the best and the return value can be the new size, else use also a pointer for *size* :

```
int addStudent(student st, student ** stArray, size_t * size);
```

and the return value can be used to indicate if the *realloc* was possible or not.

Note I considered above *stArray* is not the address where *st* can be *safely* copied because the name contains 'add' and it is not for instance 'setStudent' or 'saveStudent' etc, and also because the function return a value whose must have a meaning. But if this is the case just do *memcpy(stArray, st, sizeof(st));* and I really do not know the interest of the return value so I cannot propose what to return.

---

Some remark about your code :

- the function *load* does not load at all the file, it only allocate a block of memory and return it non initialized
- the mode "ab+" does not allow you to read the content of the file, you will need to use "rb" (it seems you need 'b')
- if the file does not exist your *fopen* creates it, the message you write when *fopen* fails if only true when the file does not exist **and** you do not have the right to create it, but you do not indicate all the other possible reasons, do not suppose  what is the problem, use for instance *perror*.
- You never *fclose* the file, you need to do
- I hope for you the file is a binary file, I mean all fields must have a constant size in it, else your computation of the number of element inside is wrong.
- the function *load* must return the address of the array **and** its size or the number of students inside to allow later to add new student(s) in the return array

Comment: the signature is given by my teacher,  so i don't know if i'm supposed to change it

Comment: @SpyrosMouchlianitis clearly that signature does not allow to add a new student, can you contact him to speak about that ? Furthermore where do you add the new student ? I supposed at the end in my answer because this is the cheaper

Comment: @SpyrosMouchlianitis I edited my answer in case *addStudent* just does a *memcpy* but I do not trust on that

Comment: thanks for all your help. Thankfully I  have a long deadline so I hope I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach and it worked. Thank you everyone for your help. I don't think this question will help anyone. Don't waste your time.